# Nasm - How does the program keep track of which register has stored negative or positive values

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-registers, flags, twos-complement

Obviously there is the Sign-Flag. But when I have a code chunk like:

```
             ;starts with parry, zero set
mov eax, 100 ; mov does not affect the flags
neg eax      ; sets carry, adjust and sign, unsets zero
mov ebx, 4000000000; mov does not affect the flags
mov ecx, eax ; mov does not affect the flags
mov edx, 50  ; mov does not affect the flags

add ebx, edx ; unsets all set flags, value of ebx is 4000000050
```

I have some trouble understanding how the program knows that `add ebx, edx` is `4000000050`.

Remember that the sign flag was still set from negating `eax`.

And because assembly has no types like C which distinguish between `signed` and `unsigned` and `ebx` highest bit is set, the value stored in `ebx` could be its real value or it could be its 2's complement. We don't know.

At least that is my understanding. So how does the program knows that `ebx` is `+4000000000` and not a negative value which 2's complement is `4000000000` in binary.

Answer (score 4):

The processor doesn't know. It is the responsibility of the programmer to keep track of which registers/memory locations contain signed numbers and which contain unsigned numbers.

A 32-bit register can either store numbers in the range -2147483648 .. 2147483647 *or* in the range 0 .. 4294967295. The processor doesn't know which of these two ranges the programmer intends to use. The beauty of 2's complement arithmetic is that the processor can perform most operations without needing to know.

Some of the operations where the processor does need to know are: division, multiplication where the result is twice the width of the operands, and comparison. For multiplication and division, there are separate opcodes for signed vs. unsigned. For comparison, the comparison opcode is the same, but the conditional branch opcodes used to check the result of the comparison are different depending on whether the programmer wants to treat the operands as signed or unsigned.

Comment: I should add some examples with actual numbers, but I'm out of time, so hopefully I can come back later and do that, or someone else can add them.

Comment: So when I compare ebx and ecx, with ebx containing -2147483648  and ecx containing 2147483648 the opcode of the comparison would be the same. But when using ```jz```,  ```jnz```, ```jge``` etc. after that, their opcode would differ? Is that something the assembly works out itself? Because I never used special instructions depending of the registers content value being positive or negative. I am sorry but I have trouble understanding that.

Comment: @MenNotAtWork: Notice that `ja` (unsigned above) and jg` (signed greater) are different instructions with different mnemonics as well as different opcodes.  (all listed in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc).  See also http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt for how different flags get set by the same ALU operations (carry vs. overflow and sign).

Comment: No, the assembler doesn’t work it out, because it doesn’t know. Also, it’s not a question of whether the operands are **positive** or **negative**. The thing you need to keep in mind is whether the operands are **signed** or **unsigned**. You would use `jge` (for example) for signed operands, and `jae` for unsigned. `je` and `jne` are the same, of course.